# How to inject a bean into another getter-based bean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dependency-injection

I would like to inject my `dataSource` bean into my `sessionFactory` bean in the following configuration :

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Bean(name="dataSource")
    public javax.sql.DataSource getDataSource(){
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        //set dataSource parameters from a .properties file
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name="sessionFactory")
    @Scope("singleton")
    public  FactoryBean<SessionFactory> getSessionFactory(){
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        //How to reference/inject/autowire the dataSource bean declared above in the sessionFactory#dataSource property ??
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

How may I achieve that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it a few ways. I'm simplifying below to include all cases with working examples.

**Method #1 - Auto-injection by Type**

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Bean
    public A getMyA() {
        return new A();
    }

    @Bean
    public B getMyB(A a) {
        System.out.println(a != null);
        return new B();
    }
}

class A {}
class B {}
```

**Method #2 - Explicit injection by Type**

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Bean
    public A getMyA() {
        return new A();
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public B getMyB(A a) {
        System.out.println(a != null);
        return new B();
    }
}

class A {}
class B {}
```

**Method #3 - Injection by Name**
*You are attempting this one*

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Bean(name = "myOtherBeanName")
    public A getMyA() {
        return new A();
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public B getMyB(@Qualifier("myOtherBeanName") A a) {
        System.out.println(a != null);
        return new B();
    }
}

class A {}
class B {}
```

**Method #4 - Non injection / Explicit method call**

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Bean(name = "myOtherBeanName")
    public A getMyA() {
        return new A();
    }

    @Bean
    public B getMyB() {
        // call me as usual - getMyA()
        return new B();
    }
}

class A {}
class B {}
```

There are so many ways it's really becoming a matter of taste/preference.

All the above can be test-run using a minimal Main class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(HibernateConfig.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code should work

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public javax.sql.DataSource getDataSource() {
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    @Scope("singleton")
    public FactoryBean<SessionFactory> getSessionFactory(javax.sql.DataSource dataSource){
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Spring provides a mechanism where we can pass such bean dependencies with @Bean method parameters. They are injected by the framework just like a constructor dependencies are resolved.